# I need help getting my code to look like this:

Tags: java

I need help getting my code output to look like the image below and I am not sure what I am doing wrong and I need to have my code output indented and cant remember how to indent it.

Here is my code currently:

```
// Fig. 18.3: FactorialCalculator.java
// Recursive factorial method.

public class Assignment_6_1 
{
    // recursive method factorial (assumes its parameter is >= 0
    static StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

    public static long factorial(long number) 
{
        if (number == 0) // test for base case
        {
            return 1; 
        } else {// recursion step         
            if (s.length() == 0) {
                s.append(number).append("*").append(number - 1);
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

                }
                System.out.println(number + " * " + (number - 1) + "!");
                s.append("*").append(number).append("*").append(number - 1);
            }
            return number * factorial(number - 1);
        }
    }

    // output factorials for values 0-21
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hannah Coffey - Lab 6");
        // calculate the factorials of 0 through 20
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 25; counter++) {
            s = new StringBuilder();
            System.out.println(counter + "!");
            System.out.printf("%d! = %d%n", counter, factorial(counter));
        }
    }
} // end class FactorialCalculator
```

Here is what I need it to look like and not sure what I am doing wrong:

[image]

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

My program currently looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rtwtf.png)

Comment: And what does the output look like currently?

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I added a photo of what the output currently looks like

Comment: why do you have an empty for statement ? You have no attempt of indentation here ...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
 public static long factorial(long number){
         if (number == 0) // test for base case
         {
             return 1;
         } else {// recursion step
             if (s.length() == 0) {
                 s.append(number).append("*").append(number - 1);
             } else {
                 String spaces = "";
                 for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
                     spaces = spaces+" ";
                 }
                 if(number==1)
                    System.out.println(" Base Case: 1");
                 else {
                    System.out.println(spaces + "Recursive call:" + number + " * fact(" + (number - 1) + ")"); 
                    s.append("*").append(number).append("*").append(number - 1);
                 }
             }
        return number * factorial(number - 1);
         }
     }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hannah Coffey - Lab 6");
    // calculate the factorials of 0 through 20
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 25; counter++) {
        s = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            spaces = spaces+" ";
        }
        System.out.println(spaces+"Recursive call:"+counter + "!");
        System.out.printf("%d! = %d%n", counter, factorial(counter));
    }
}
```

Comment: it says that there are syntax errors.

Comment: Thank you I fixed it. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: `spaces+" "` is not efficient ... it will instanciate a `String` on each iteration.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted?

Comment: Also AxelH feel free to edit my answer

Comment: Matt, I upvoted it but I think others downvoted it and your code was very helpful and worked great.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can pad a `String` using `String.format` like this :

```
String.format("%10s", "foo");
```

It will create a left padding of 7 spaces `7 + foo.length = 10;`

Now, we can render that dynamic like :

```
public static String padding( int i ) {
    return i == 0 ? "" : String.format( "%" + i + "s", "" );
}
```

Just pass the number of spaces and let the formatter do the job.

```
for(int i = 5; i >= 0; --i){
    System.out.println(padding(i) + "i");
}
```

Output :

```
     5
    4
   3
  2
 1
0
```